# Usage question: "Relation" vs. "Relationship"

Tags: suffixes

What is the difference between *relation* and *relationship*?

What's the purpose of the suffix?

Comment: Well for instance, you can have a relationship with a relation, but probably not the other way 'round. Have you looked these words up in a dictionary?

Comment: (I've reworded your query about the suffix. Let me know if this wasn't your meaning.)

Comment: A "relation", in one sense, is someone who's related to you -- brother, cousin, etc.  A "relationship" (in the most similar sense) is a business or social "bond" between two entities -- people, companies, etc.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I posted a link of a related question in the above comment. If you don't find it satisfactory, please edit your question to be more specific. Thanks.